# Svelte hot module reload settings for rollup config in a monorepo

Tags: module, reload, svelte, rollup, monorepo

I have a Monorepo App which requires components to be included from an external folder (outside of the app root folder). I want to create a hot reload in my rollup.config file. currently when I make any change in the component (which are in an external folder). I have to restart the dev server by "pnpm run dev'. I want the app to be reloaded automatically

Comment: are you doing the rollup for the ENTIRE monorepo or just the svelte app? I think `rollup-plugin-livereload` just reloads for changes to the `input` directory of the `rollup.config.js` file

Comment: Yes the rollup doing reload onyl for the input directory app. I want it to reload when i change the component (which are not inside input directory).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this challenge, I wrote a rollup plugin just for this purpose [rollup-plugin-reloadsite](https://github.com/mugendi/rollup-plugin-reloadsite) that I hope helps. Even better is that you can watch multiple directories (not just your input and output directories) and also watch other assets like images and html files.